# AC Drain Line Redo

Tags: drain, pipe

I've moved into a new home here in central Florida, and had a new AC system installed.

They attached the drain line to the old existing pipe that was there with the old system.

Unfortunately, this pipe doesn't have a very good slope to it before it runs under the house and then back up and outside. Because of this I always seem to have an issue with clogged pipes.

I think a good solution for me would be to make a new pipe and reroute it along the back side wall of my garage with its own natural slope then going through the wall of the garage outside.

I was wondering if this is okay or does the pipe need to go underground under the house and then up and out?

Comment: Have you tried blowing it out with a hose and water for a minute or so?

Comment: Not yet. Thats going to be my next step but I have a very powerful shop vac that i used to blow out the line and that seemed to get everything out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used an existing drain to save you some money and save themselves some work. I can't think of a reason the drain would have to run under the house other than they wanted it to exit the house there for aesthetic reasons. What you propose sounds fine. If you have a consistent slope that should keep it from clogging. One thing to consider is to put a trap in it to keep insects from crawling through the line into the AC unit. Make the trap easy to clean.

Comment: I think you're right. One reason I was asking is to make sure theres no weird code that says you need to go underground. As for a trap I was planning on buying a coupling and they just attaching some hardware cloth to one side so that i can take it off and put it back on again with ease

Comment: If the drain is just going onto the ground, it might be practical for the water to drip onto gravel with a little sand on it to diffuse the flow onto the ground